# SQL Syntax for checking duplicates prior to update (not DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a syntactical question with attempting an `UPDATE` if 2 `non key` fields are matched. -- `INSERT` if not matched.

Let me start by saying I have a **working query** that involves a `SELECT` with an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.  Now I am just curious, can it be done differently?

Out of sheer curiosity, I am trying this in a manner that will not require the `primary key`. This really is just an experiment to see if it can be done.

What I want is **like** `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` --  However:

1. let's pretend I don't know the `key` , and
2. let's pretend I *can't get* the key with a `SELECT`

Here is the data structure I have:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
|   id   |    contractor_id    |    email_type_id    |    email_address    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE `email_list` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `contractor_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email_address` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Now what I am trying to do **without a select** and **without ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** is --  If `contractor_id` *and* `email_type_id` are matched -- `UPDATE` the `email_address` -- else `INSERT`.

If have tried this -- (I know I am breaking my own rule of no SELECT):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM email_list WHERE contractor_id = 1166)
    UPDATE email_list SET (email_address='herky_jerky@snailmail.com')
    WHERE contractor_id = 1166 AND email_type_id = 4
ELSE
    INSERT INTO email_list VALUES (
     contractor_id = 1166, 
     email_type_id = 4, 
     email_address = 'herky_jerky@snailmail.com');
```

I understand **why** this doesn't work .. I just don't know what the fix for it is --  It feels a little clunky too using an `IF - ELSE` statement.  Also I don't want to use a `SELECT` --  So then I thought about using just an `IF` like:

```
UPDATE email_list SET email_address = 'herky@jerky.com' 
WHERE contractor_id = 1166 AND email_type_id = 4
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
    INSERT INTO email_list VALUES (
    contractor_id = 1166, 
    email_type_id = 4, 
    email_address = 'herky@jerky.com');
```

But I don't understand why that one doesn't work.  This is just an exercise to see how creative one can be with this type of query.  I think both of my ideas are doable --  Can anyone find a fix for either query to make it work?

I'd also love to see other, more creative, ways of attempting what I am asking as well!

Comment: You need a `;` at the end of the `UPDATE` query before the `IF`.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`?

Comment: All this code needs to be in a stored procedure in order to use `IF`.

Comment: All these restrictions about what you don't want to use seem really arbitrary. Why are you tying your hands and not allowing yourself to use the features that SQL provides?

Comment: Anyway, the last code should work if you add the missing `;` between the statements.

Comment: They seem arbitrary if you're not curious about the "other ways" to create a statement, I agree ..  BUT -- Like I said -- Out of curiosity .. I am not doing this to "get it done" --  I already have a working statement --  I was just curious if there were any more creative ways of doing it ..

Comment: All the ways I've done this have involved `INSERT ... SELECT`.

Comment: Note that your `UPDATE` + `IF` only works when you're just doing 1 row. If you're trying to do multiple rows, you're pretty much forced to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY` or `INSERT ... SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd implement this using an `UPDATE` followed by a test of `ROW_COUNT()` and if no rows were updated, then `INSERT`.

```
drop table if exists t;

create table t (id int, x int, y int, str varchar(255));

insert into t (id, x, y, str) values (1, 2, 3, 'foo');

select * from t;

update t set str = 'bar'
where x = 2 and y = 3;

insert into t (id, x, y, str)
select 1, 2, 3, 'inserted'
from dual
where row_count() = 0;

select * from t;

update t set str = 'baz'
where x = 20 and y = 30;

insert into t (id, x, y, str)
select 10, 20, 30, 'baz'
from dual
where row_count() = 0;

select * from t;

drop table t;
```

You can see it in action here: https://rextester.com/FRFTE79537

The idea here is you do the `UPDATE` first, followed by an `INSERT ... SELECT` where the `SELECT` only returns a row *if* `ROW_COUNT() = 0` is true, and that's only true if the `UPDATE` didn't match any rows.